# EXTJS 5 : How to have the checkbox selected only when clicking on checkbox in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, grid, extjs5

Could you please let me know how to have the row selected in the grid only when clicking on the checkbox and not when clicking on any other cell in the grid.

I also tried to override the same using the below code but was unable to achieve the desired result.....

```
Ext.CheckboxSelectionModel = Ext.extend(Ext.selection.CheckboxModel, {
beforeselect: function (grid, record, index, eOpts) {
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally... after getting no proper tweak/hack for the same.. I had posted the same in extjs forum and then have tagged the same as a bug which would be fixed in v5.0.2...
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?291021-EXTJS-5-How-to-have-the-checkbox-selected-only-when-clicking-on-checkbox-in-grid&p=1063513#post1063513

Answer (score 1):

this is a ExtJS 5 bug

its work easily

```
selModel : Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
    checkOnly: true,
});
```

but only in ExtJS 5.0.2 its fixed

proof:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?290630

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that would be is to listen for [cellClick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-cellclick) event and check if cellIndex matches your checkbox cell index. Use selectionModel.[deselect](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-deselect)/deselectAll if cellClick doesn't match.

```
cellclick: function (thisRef, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts){
    if (cellIndex !== 0){ //Considering index 0 is checkbox column
        thisRef.selModel.deselect(record);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for the solution... I had already tried that but the problem is that in my scenario I had to have the selection persists once the checkbox is checked and then any of the same row cell is edited.... And that was leading to handling of both selection and deselection which I wanted to avoid.